# In Flex Alert.show, prevent Escape key closing the parent window

Tags: apache-flex

After Flex `Alert.show` opens an dialog with a CANCEL button, when I press the ESCAPE key it will close the alert box. But how can I prevent this key event being transferred to the parent window? The parent may also register ESCAPE as a close key, and then it will close too.

Answer (score 0):

The [Alert.show](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html#show%28%29) method returns an instance to the Alert class.  You can listen for escape on the Alert; and then stop propagation in your event listener.  This is psuedo code; but:

```
// in some method somewhere
// create Alert Class
var myAlert : Alert = Alert.show('test','test');
// listen for keyboard event
myAlert.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

//... elsewhere in code
protected function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
  if(event.charCode =Keyboard.ESCAPE){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
}
```